# htaccess css images

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've searched all similar questions and failed:

I wrote a url rewrite similar to the one implemented in zend framework (PHP):

```
localhost/user/new
```

Calls for a Controller Named `UserController` and executes a function `NewAction`. Works like a charm.

But I have some problems with `$_GET`, `$_POST` and Images and I guess it's because of the htaccess file. It goes like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

I use jQuery ui and jQuery UI uses relative links in its CSS.

If I do something like this

```
http://localhost/login
```

the images load fine and everything works.

If I add a trailing slash like `http://localhost/login/` or `http://localhost/login/param1`, the image gets loaded, but the controller gets called, too:

```
http://localhost/login/param1/images/ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png
```

I don't get how to correct this. There is also a pending problem with post & get via forms, but I guess that this maybe related, so I just want to clear this.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let me explain:

the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` checks if you try to load a file that does not really exist on your server, `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` checks if you try to load a directory that does not really exist on your server.

so if you try to load a file that does not exist it is redirected to index.php.

if your url is 'http://localhost/login/param1/images/ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png' then there must be an image named ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png in a directory calles images which lies in a directory called param1 which lies in a directory called login which lies in your server-root-folder. if there is no such directory structure or image then the request ist send to index.php

if you want to load the image images/ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png then dont put the login/param1 before it.

maybe including the jquery-css using an absolute link will solve your problem.

```
<link href="http://localhost/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

then the relative links in the css file will be relative to the path specified in that link-tag.

Comment: Zuloo Answer worked, but I had to change the last line of my .htaccess to the following:

    RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$ index.php