# Background image disappears after editing .htaccess

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

this is my first time with editing .htaccess, the situation is that I need to restrict access to a website for anyone except several IP-addresses and redirect others to a specific page. To do that I am using the following code in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
RewriteRule (.*) index.html [QSA,L]
```

The problem begins when I change the IP in this file - the background image which is used for the  in index.html and stated in its internal css just stops appearing. I have tested this in Chrome and Firefox, in Firefox the background image reappears when the IP is changed to the one I have, in Chrome it doesn't reappear even after the IP changed back. I hope someone will be able to help me.

Best regards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess css images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322997/htaccess-css-images)

Comment: Of course it “disappears”, because you are rewriting _everything_ to index.html – and that includes the request the browser makes for the image. So the browser expects image data, but gets an HTML document instead – and it can not display that as an image, of course.

Comment: Thank you for revealing the source of this issue. I suspected that it might be the problem. Could you please help me fix this code so it would include an exception for the image in the root directory? It would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While rewriting is a powerful technique, it has many caveats and is relatively complex to get right. Here, the solution is not to use mod_rewrite at all. Apache's [mod_authz_host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_host.html) module allows you to use the `Require` directive to specify which IP addresses are allowed to access resources.

If you need to display a specific page in case the `Require` is not satisfied, just specify an [ErrorDocument](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errordocument) for the error 403 (forbidden) which will be triggered.

If the error page then needs to access other resources, they need to bypass the IP restriction and be allowed using the `Require` directive:

Here is how your .htaccess file will look like:

```
Require ip XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
ErrorDocument 403 /index.html
<Files "specific_image.png">
     Require all granted
</Files>
```

Note that this causes an *internal* redirection in Apache.

If you want an external redirection and have the user have the actual index.html file in their browser's address bar, the configuration becomes a little bit more complicated because the file must be specifically allowed:

```
Require ip XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
ErrorDocument 403 %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.html
<Files "index.html">
    Require all granted
</Files>
<Files "specific_image.png">
     Require all granted
</Files>
```

Note the use of variables to avoid hard-coding the absolute URL to the index.html file. Using a complete URL here is necessary to trigger the external redirection.

Comment: `Require ip XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` – you can’t use `Require` like that – quote apache manual, _“This directive selects which authenticated users can access a resource.”_ If you want to grant access based on the requesting client’s IP address, you need to use the [`Allow`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow) directive.

Comment: @CBroe I'm assuming Apache 2.4 since it has been released for ages. The configuration has changed a lot since the 2.2 releases.

Comment: I stand corrected; I wasn’t aware that the scope of this directive had changed considerably with 2.4.

Comment: @CBroe Indeed, I had to migrate a few servers from 2.2 to 2.4 at some point. Even though Apache 2.4 provides a  `mod_access_compat` module, I wanted to avoid it, so it was definitly not a smooth process :)

Comment: Thank you, I am very grateful for your help.